# Set shell script Variable to output of command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im trying to cd into the md5 hash of whatever variable is set into the script but I do not get the correct value of md5, I think it has something to do with how I'm declaring my variables. Thank you for any help!

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
md5=$(-n $var1 | md5sum)
cd /var/www/html/$md5
```

I expected it to take me to a directory given by the md5 hash:

```
$ ./myscript hello
(no output)
$ pwd
/var/www/html/5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

Instead, it gives me errors and tries to `cd` to the wrong path:

```
$ ./myscript hello
./myscript: line 3: -n: command not found
./myscript: line 4: cd: /var/www/html/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e: No such file or directory
$ pwd
/home/me
```

The md5sum it incorrectly tries to cd to is also the same no matter which value I input.

Comment: What are you getting in that variable?

Comment: it outputs the same md5 hash everytime no matter what variable i pass in

Comment: Does the folder with the md5sum created before? i.e. for all your valid input arguments, will there exist a target folder with its hash value?

Comment: yes the folders are already created

Comment: Do you have a command `-n` in a directory on your PATH?  Probably not.  You probably should be using `md5=$(printf '%s' "$1" | md5sum)` or thereabouts (I wouldn't use `echo -n` but there are many who would).  You need to include double quotes around arguments, too, if there are spaces or special characters to be preserved.

Comment: Incidentally, a Google search for 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' confirms that this is what you get when you compute the MD5 checksum of an empty file (e.g. `/dev/null` on Unix-like systems), or when there's no input on standard input, etc.  Since the failed `-n` command produces no output, the `md5sum` command gets no input and outputs the same hash every time.

Answer (score 0):

This works as a solution for anyone else having this issue

```
#!/bin/bash
md5=$*
hash="$(echo -n "$md5" | md5sum )"
cd /var/www/html/$hash
```

Comment: This won't navigate to the hash directory name path, since the script is executed on the child shell which is not reflected up. Refer my answer above!

Comment: @Inian all you have do is ". md5 name"

Comment: Am not sure what's that supposed to mean!

Comment: @Inian when you do "." or "source" before you run a shell script you don't have to worry about it only being executed in the child shell

Comment: Aah! You meant that! Makes sense! Checkout my answer too if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
md5=$(-n $var1 | md5sum)
cd /var/www/html/$md5
```

This has a few issues:

1. `-n` is not a valid command in the pipeline `-n $var1 | md5sum`.
2. `md5sum` returns more than just the MD5 digest.
3. Changing the directory in a script will not be reflected in the calling shell.
4. Input is used unquoted.

I would write a shell function for this, rather than a script:

```
function md5cd {
  dir="$( printf "%s" "$1" | md5sum - | cut -d ' ' -f 1 )"
  cd /var/www/html/"$dir" || return 1
}
```

The function computes the MD5 digest of the given string using `md5sum` and cuts off the filename (`-`) that's part of the output. It then changes directory to the specified location. If the target directory does not exist, it signals this by returning a non-zero exit status.

Extending it to `cd` to a path constructed from the path on the command line, but with the last path element changed into a MD5 digest (just for fun):

```
function md5cd {
  word="${1##*/}"

  if [[ "$word" == "$1" ]]; then
    prefix="."
  else
    prefix="${1%/*}"
  fi

  dir="$( cut -d ' ' -f 1 <( printf "%s" "$word" | md5sum - ) )"
  cd "$prefix"/"$dir" || return 1
}
```

Testing it:

```
$ pwd
/home/myself

$ echo -n "hex this" | md5sum
990c0fc93296f9eed6651729c1c726d4  -

$ mkdir /tmp/990c0fc93296f9eed6651729c1c726d4

$ md5cd /tmp/"hex this"

$ pwd
/tmp/990c0fc93296f9eed6651729c1c726d4
```